# Put word count of lines into variable

Tags: external-command, variables, shell, system

I can get a word count of a range of lines, by doing something like this:

```
:1,20w !wc -w
```

(where that gets lines 1 to 20, writes (`w`) them to the external shell command (`!`) `wc -w`, and outputs the result in the info area.

I can set the result of a shell command to a variable if I do something like this:

```
:let wc = system('wc -w')
```

(so then if I issue the command `:echo wc`, it displays..., ah, `0` in the info area, because I didn't give wc any text to parse.

So how do I tell the `system` command which lines to pass to the external shell command it calls?

Comment: `:help system()` takes `input` (though you'd probably rather use `systemlist()`). Use `getline()` or `getbufline()` to get lines from a buffer

Comment: Have you considered/tried using `wordcount()` instead? (Not 100% sure if it will work: you'd need to set visual mode in order to apply it to your range.)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the lines to be piped to the shell command via an arg to the `system` function call:

```
:let wc=system('wc -c',getline(1,20))
```

As, @d-ben-knoble suggested, care of the `system` function help page.

Comment: Note that the `wc` variable here ends with a newline (`\n`), as that's what `wc` will output, which can be real confusing if you use it for comparison or echo'ing later. You probably want to call `trim()` on the output to remove it like so: `:let wc = system('wc -c', getline(1, 20))->trim()`